# Debugging high upstream_header_time in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy server with the following setup

```
Client -> Nginx -> Rails Upstream
```

For ~1% of the requests, I noticed that $http_header_time is ~5s. The upstream logs indicate that the said requests were completed in ~100ms.

How can I debug this discrepancy? Also, is it possible to log the time taken by Nginx to forward the request to upstream?